# this breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document in project asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, forms, web

I'm trying too much to remove all DLL inside projects in solution and add again from debug folder but not going well.
In solution asp.net web forms contain multi project
[image]

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm4wl.png):

Comment: Are you currently running this application and have you made changes while it was running? If so then these won't be picked up by the debugger. You will need to stop debugging and rebuild the solution. If this is not the case, could you make sure you have place the breakpoint in the actual  doc, and not a doc.temp

Comment: No I'm edit in code then clean and rebuild then like pic in screenshot

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Can you be ensure about this area is "Debug". If it is "Release", you may face this problem.

Comment: yes i selected debug and any cpu also not working

Comment: after search I'm looking at file like .pdb file in project when rebuild so i need to stop this generated because these files may be stopped debugger how to stop this?